# How to calculate cumulative sum in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got this table. And want to multiple cumulative sum of product 4355 to 4334.

1. How can i calculate cumulative sum?

[image]

Comment: Have you googled the question?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have read the dataframe as `df`

```
import numpy as np

sales_array = df["Sale"].values
result = np.sum(sales_array)
print(result)
```

Comment: but is that cumuluative? i found sumcum function, which is not working for me

Comment: fyi you can use `df[col].cumsum()` to calculate the cumulative sum of a row in a dataframe